# pip installs to hidden (?) directory?

Tags: python, pip

So, I've installed `xlsxwriter` via `pip` just fine -- scripts run no problem.  My issue is that I can't find where the actual files are installed to (because PyCharm IDE doesn't detect that `xlsxwriter` is actually installed and has that annoying red underline)

So, as you can see in the attached picture, when I run `pip uninstall xlsxwriter` it is showing that it's installed in `\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\`
but that folder simply does not exist as far as I can tell, not even as a hidden directory.

In the end, I really just want PyCharm to stop underlining modules that are installed, but this appears to be the case with a few different modules and I just want to get to the bottom of it.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/BxK4oA5.png]

Comment: Do you have multiple python versions installed? And if so could it be that you installed xlsxwriter to a python version different from that in PyCharm?

Comment: Are you sure @jlink7? Have you tried to open it through a file explorer?

Comment: I'm positive, I've done it in both windows file explorer and through the command prompt (shown).

I also only have one version of Python installed, in fact the computer itself is a pretty clean install.